# ProgressDialog in a AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog, symbols

I'm having trouble using a `ProgressDialog` in a `AsyncTask`.

In `onPreExecute()`I start the `ProgressDialog`, but when I finish the `ProgressDialog` in `onPosTExecute()` I get the error

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'progresso'
```

Here is my code:

```
 private class DataTransfer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    private ProgressDialog progresso;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

        super.onPreExecute();

        progresso.setIndeterminate(true);
        progresso.setCancelable(false);
        progresso.setMessage("Your message");
        progresso.show();
    }


    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        return postData();
    }


    public String postData() {
        String origresponseText = "";
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("*****"); //URL here
        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("teste", "OK"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("crc", "010101"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            origresponseText = readContent(response);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.i("ClientProtocolException", e.toString());
            cancel(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("IOException", e.toString());
            cancel(true);
        }

           String responseText = origresponseText;
        Log.i("String", responseText);
           return responseText;

    }

    public String readContent(HttpResponse response) {
        String text = "";
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            text = sb.toString();
        } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            try {

                in.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }

        return text;
    }


    protected void onCancelled(String result) {
        Log.i("Async", "Cancelled");
    }



@Override
    private void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");


    progresso.dismiss();
        Log.i("Async", "PostExecute");
        Log.i("Result", result);

    }

}
```

Comment: Your English is fine so no reason to apologize in posts :)

Answer (score 1):

In `onPreExecute()`, you have

```
progresso
```

and you have it declared that way above

```
private ProgressDialog progresso;
```

but in `onPostExecute()` you have

```
progressBar
```

simply change that to

```
@Override
private void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");

    progresso.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

You are not initializing progress dialog anywhere. Construct it before using:

```
progressBar = new ProgressDialog(YourActivityName.this);
```

Documentation is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html).

Comment: Good catch. I missed that it wasn't being initialized. Just payed attention to the initial problem.

Comment: This is for a ProgressBar, but how i do for a ProgressDialog?

Answer (score 0):

About the first problem, that was a wiriting mistake, here in stackoverflow. I was using "progressBar" to a ProgressDialog, then, when editing the topic I edited and changed "progressBar" by "progress", but forgot to change the onPostExecute. In my original code, i used "progressBar". Already fix in the post.

**EDIT:** I'm feeling so dumb right now. I found the error. I put the "OnPostExecute ()" out of class "DataTransfer" and did not even realize. Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialise your progress dialog.. here is the update code

```
    private class DataTransfer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    private ProgressDialog progresso;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

        super.onPreExecute();
        progresso =new ProgessDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progresso.setIndeterminate(true);
        progresso.setCancelable(false);
        progresso.setMessage("Your message");
        progresso.show();
    }


    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        return postData();
    }


    public String postData() {
        String origresponseText = "";
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("*****"); //URL here
        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("teste", "OK"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("crc", "010101"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            origresponseText = readContent(response);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.i("ClientProtocolException", e.toString());
            cancel(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("IOException", e.toString());
            cancel(true);
        }

           String responseText = origresponseText;
        Log.i("String", responseText);
           return responseText;

    }

    public String readContent(HttpResponse response) {
        String text = "";
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            text = sb.toString();
        } catch (IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            try {

                in.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }

        return text;
    }


    protected void onCancelled(String result) {
        Log.i("Async", "Cancelled");
    }



@Override
    private void onPostExecute(String result) {
    progresso.dismiss();
        Log.i("Async", "PostExecute");
        Log.i("Result", result);

    }

}
```